# Which nationality is All Might?

Tags: my-hero-academia

All Might is blond, and he uses an American-themed suit, and labels all his attacks with American city names.

At first, I thought he could be American, but then he has a Japanese name and works in Japan.

Is All Might Japanese, American, some other nationality, or is it unknown?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

His full name is Toshinori Yagi which is a Japanese name as you said and according to wiki his birthplace is Tokyo.

Other evidences are:

- His mentor, Nana Shimura, is also Japanese.
- All Might also go to  U.A. High School and his homeroom teacher was Gran Torino.

Comment: His superhero persona is probably intentionally made to look American. Not just the names of his attacks, but also Americans in anime are often drawn as giant blonde, blue eyed, square jawed men, who are loud and boisterous, so it is very cartoonishly stereotypical. I imagine it makes a good cover for All Might who has a secret identity as a scrawny Japanese man with a completely different personality from All Might, plus it's a shout out to the place where the superhero genre originated.

Comment: but this doesnt explain endeavor scene though. Remember even tsukauchi did not try to correct endeavor when he referred all might as American. tsukauchi is a close friend of all might btw so even he did not correct endeavor which more likely means that all might is american

Answer (score 2):

On season 3 episode 20, the girl did call All Might a Japanese hero. But when they were rescuing Bakugo from the League of Villains, Endeavor specifically said, "Why does the American get to go in there."

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, today in episode #20 of season 3, her "niece" (if she's her real niece or just call him "uncle" because he's close to her) called him "japanese hero", so no doubt he's japanese. (And they told All Might studied in United States, so that's probably why he looks american)

Answer (score -1):

Nope! American. Before the take down of All for one the #2 hero Endeavor said and I quote “Why do we get stuck out here while the AMERICAN gets to barge in!” ALMIGHT is American. However I don’t doubt he was raised in Tokyo and has family who is Japanese but he is American. He also uses Detroit etc as names for his power moves. You don’t just name something Detroit unless you were raised there lol even living there for a short time doesn’t make sense. It is obviously a shout out to his home town, perhaps where he was born.

Comment: Nope. In Two Heroes, in a flashback, it was explicitly stated that (while in America), All Might was simply an "Exchange Student from Japan". It's just fitting that all the Americans could only speak Japanese.

Comment: @aytimothy then why did endeavor say that sentence? did he mistake all might to be American?

Comment: @theprogrammer He's derogatorily commenting on All Might's theme/motif, which is an American Muscleman.