# Why do the top 10 heroes in Boku no Hero Academia only come from Japan?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In *Boku no Hero Academia*, we know the world is not limited to only Japan; there are America and other countries as stated especially in the *BNHA: Two Heroes* movie. But why are the known top 10 heroes (probably all the best heroes) Japanese? Endeavor, Jeanist, Edgeshot, etc. are all from Japan, even All Might (although he's been in the USA doing hero work).

Is there another top hero that is actually not Japanese or not from Japan? Or is it just that Kohei Horikoshi makes Japan so much stronger in this series?

Comment: Isn't all might like american tho?

Comment: @Jay [not really](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/47490)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Hero Billboard Chart that is usually mentioned in the manga is not the world rankings. This should be obvious since only Japanese heroes are in there and since it is named *Hero Billboard Chart JP* in the manga. [image]

To quote from the [wiki](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Hero_Billboard_Chart_JP),

> The Hero Billboard Chart JP is an event that presents the official rankings of **Japanese Pro Heroes**.

If I have to guess, no top heroes from other nations are mentioned since mentioning them would not be relevant to the story as it is for now.

Comment: I'm not a manga reader so I didn't know about this chart. Kinda ambiguous that they haven't mentioned the chart clearly in current anime

Comment: @gameon67 I see. I thought it was mentioned. I also watched the anime first before reading the manga and during watching, the thought of the top 10 heroes being a worldwide ranking never occurred to me. I have always assumed that the top heroes repeatedly mentioned throughout the anime must be part of the Japanese ranking only.

Comment: Although with the latest movie, I am not sure if the manga would finally involve events and story arcs centered outside Japan. By the way, the rankings were shown after the Shie Hassaikai Arc, which would probably explain why anime watchers do not know about it. I apologize as I assumed you read the manga already.

Comment: No need to apologize, thanks for clarifying my confusion